# How can I connect from a mac to a windows?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have two computers on the same local networks and I have installed OpenSSH Server on the windows and activated the 22 port communication on the windows.

Then in my mac i put

```
ssh username@ip_of_windows
```

however, it doesn't let me connect on terminal. The connection just disappears without any error. What am I missing?

Comment: Try (from the Mac Explorer)  SMB://windowsIP/sharedfolder.  This works from a Linux machine on my network to a Windows machine on my network.

Comment: Some debugging thoughts: Can you do `ssh localhost` on your Windows machine? Can you try to use `ssh -vv` on your Mac to get more logs? Can you `ping` through to your Windows machine from you Mac?

Comment: @John Your suggestion seems to be to mount a smb share. How does this help in opening a terminal window through ssh?

Comment: It is a command to map a folder on the Windows machine so you can see it in the Mac Explorer Window.

Comment: Are you trying to authenticate with your MacOS user or your Windows user? Only your Windows user would work, you likely will also have to indicate the machine name and the username, while connecting to the Windows machine. The logs from the OpenSSH Server would tell you exactly what happen.

Comment: You could try and run the command with a verbose flag to get more of an idea as to what is going on. `ssh -v user@IP-Address`